# Recovering Wifi Profile Security Key with - in name argument

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm attempting to show the Security key for a specific profile.

The command:

```
netsh wlan show all
```

displays a list of all my profiles, including the one I'm attempting to recover (HOME-EB52)

However, when I attempt:

```
netsh wlan show profile name="HOME-EB52" key=clear
```

It says the profile cannot be found, even when I copy/paste.

When I try it with other profile names, it works fine. I suspect it is because of the '-' character messing with the argument. I attempted using escape characters \, /, ^ and several others with no luck.

When I enter:

```
netsh wlan show profile name=* key=clear
```

It lists all profiles, but under network key it only says "Present" or "Absent".

Is there any way to get all of the network keys to show up?

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the command prompt in 'Run As Administrator' mode to be able to reveal the Security Key with this command.

Running the netsh command in normal privilege mode will only show the status as 'Present' or 'Absent'.

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

you can use **profile** or **profiles**

Then try to find password for single profile not for a whole list becasue this won't show you passwords just ABSENT / PRESENT

```
netsh wlan show profile name="xyz" key=clear
```